# Redirige a una página no deseada

Tags: php

Al pulsar el botón Modificar, me guarda los datos correctamente, lo comprobé con varios "echo" pero me redirige siempre al fichero error404.php (cuando este fichero lo tengo para errores en la URL o datos no deseados). **Debería retornarme a panel_administrador.php cuando pulse en "Guardar".**

¿Dónde tengo el error?

**Código HTML/PHP:**

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "Clases/Accesorios.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Modificar"...
    if(isset($_POST["modificar"])){
        $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"];
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
        $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
        $precio = $_POST["precio"];
        $array_accesorios = $_POST["accesorios"];
        BD::modificarCabana($idcabana, $nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);
        BD::modificarAccesoriosPorCabana($idcabana, $array_accesorios);
        header("Refresh:0; url=panel_administrador.php");
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Atras"...
    if(isset($_POST["atras"])){
        header("Refresh:0; url=panel_administrador.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Modificar cabaña</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_modificar.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        function in_multiarray($elemento, $array, $campo){
            $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
            $bottom = 0;
            while($bottom <= $top){
                if($array[$bottom][$campo] == $elemento)
                    return true;
                else 
                    if(is_array($array[$bottom][$campo]))
                        if(in_multiarray($elemento, ($array[$bottom][$campo])))
                            return true;
                $bottom++;
            }        
            return false;
        }

        if (empty($_REQUEST['idcabana'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
            header('Location: error404.php');
        }

        //Guardamos en una variable los ids de las cabañas.
        $ids = BD::obtenerIDsCabanas();
        //Si ese id no está en la tabla cabanas, mostramos un error.
        if(!in_multiarray($_REQUEST["idcabana"], $ids, "idcabana")){
            header('Location: error404.php');
        }else{
        ?>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div id="mostrar_datos">
            <!-- Modificar cabaña -->
            <form action="modificar.php" name="modificar" id="modificar" method="POST">
            <?php $objeto_cabana = BD::datosCabana($_REQUEST["idcabana"]); ?>
                <label for="idcabana">ID: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_idcabana = strlen($objeto_cabana->getIdcabana()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_idcabana; ?>" id="idcabana" name="idcabana" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getIdcabana(); ?> "/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <!-- Aqui va: <br/><br/> -->
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_nombre = strlen($objeto_cabana->getNombre()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_nombre; ?>" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getNombre(); ?> "/>
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
                    <?php
                    echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
                    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                        if($i==$objeto_cabana->getCapacidad()){
                            echo "<option value='$i' selected>$i</option>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_descripcion = strlen($objeto_cabana->getDescripcion()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_descripcion; ?>" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getDescripcion(); ?> "/>
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="precio">Precio: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_precio = strlen($objeto_cabana->getPrecio()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_precio; ?>" id="precio" name="precio" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getPrecio(); ?> "/>
                <br/><br/>

                <div class="mostrar_accesorios" id="mostrar_accesorios">
                    <center>
                        <h3><b>Accesorios</b></h3><br/>
                        <?php 
                        $objeto_accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($_REQUEST["idcabana"]);
                        $todos_accesorios = BD::todosAccesorios();
                        foreach($todos_accesorios as $objeto){
                            $existe = false;
                            foreach($objeto_accesorios as $columna){
                                //Si el accesorio global está en el accesorio de la cabaña, true.
                                if($objeto->getIdaccesorio() == $columna->getIdaccesorio()){
                                    $existe = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if($existe){
                                echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%'><img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' title='".$objeto->getDescripcion()."'/><br/><label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]' checked>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</label></div>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%'><img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' title='".$objeto->getDescripcion()."'/><br/><label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]'>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</label></div>";
                            }
                            $existe = false;        
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div style="clear:left"></div>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <form>
                            <input type="submit" value="Atrás" id="atras" name="atras" />
                        </form>
                        <!--<a href="javascript:history.back(-1);" title="Ir la página anterior">Atrás</a>-->
                        <input type="submit" value="Modificar" id="modificar" name="modificar" />
                    </center>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Si elimino esta parte del código funciona correctamente:

```
        if (empty($_REQUEST['idcabana'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
            header('Location: error404.php');
        }

        //Guardamos en una variable los ids de las cabañas.
        $ids = BD::obtenerIDsCabanas();
        //Si ese id no está en la tabla cabanas, mostramos un error.
        if(!in_multiarray($_REQUEST["idcabana"], $ids, "idcabana")){
            header('Location: error404.php');
        }else{
        ?>
```

Comment: es el header location que hace la redireccion cambialo por panel_administrador.php

Comment: Los dos header('Location: error404.php'); que tengo es para los errores. Creo que están bien ubicados.

Comment: te falta poner un `die();` o `exit();` justo después de cada `header('Location:...` de lo contrario el `PHP` continua procesando las lineas siguientes.

Comment: Tienes razón, no añadí el die(); @Marcos Intégralo en una respuesta para dartela como correcta. Así cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te esta faltando poner un [`die();`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.die.php) o [`exit();`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php) justo después de cada `header('Location:...` o de cada `header('Refresh:...` de lo contrario `PHP` continuara procesando las lineas siguientes.